How to use APA7 reference list in elsevier class document
I am creating my master's thesis in the elsevier.cls latex style, and just found out that this uses harvard style citation. I've tried to get my reference list at the end into APA7 style (requirement from university) but to no avail. Is this not possible, or how do I do this correctly? This is my preamble & the part in which I try to make the reference list.
(Preferably a solution using natbib)
\documentclass[authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption} % For customizing captions
\captionsetup{justification=centering} % Center the captions
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black}

\begin{document}

%% ...

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

The Elsevier class uses natbib by default, and there is no implementation of APA7 available for natbib. But the class provides an option nonatbib which will prevent any natbib related code from loading. You shouldn't therefore pass the authoryear option to the class either, nor should you load natbib yourself.
Because the class defines an author counter, but doesn't appear to use it, and if it did I assume only for things not relevant for your use of the class, I've undefined it so that biblatex can define its own.
Then you can just use the biblatex apa style, which implements APA7.  You need to process the file with biber instead of bibtex. If you load biblatex with the natbib=true option, you can continue to use your existing natbib citation commands, which means switching from natbib to biblatex shouldn't be too difficult. This solution is very lightly tested.
If you're unwilling to use biblatex then your best option would be to load the apacite package with the natbibapa option (still using the nonatbib option of the class) and hope that whoever checks your thesis for compliance can't tell the difference between APA6 and APA7.
\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter\let\c@author\relax\makeatother
\usepackage{csquotes} % recommended
\usepackage[english]{babel} % recommended (or with an appropriate language)
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Natbib citation commands work \citet{glashow} \citep{companion}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}

